# Wix CustomAction update UI?

Tags: wix, controls, custom-action

If I have a managed Wix Custom Action, is there anyway I can update a Control with the type of Text? I see that a progress bar can be updated by using the `session.Message`  with `InstallMessage.Progress`, but I do not see a way for updating other UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a text control you can use a property wrapped in brackets: [SOMEPROP]

Then in your CA you can say session["SOMEPROP"] = "somevalue".   Note MSI is wonky about refreshing the UI so you'll pretty much have to transition from one dialog to another to get this to work.   In other words,  on the next button of the previous dialog call the CA and in the next dialog the text control will display the text.

Comment: There are some funky scenarios where you do.

Comment: Without any way around them? I know I usually have to jump through hoops but eventually, there is always some sort of a solution.

Comment: MSI native/internal UI is limited.  Examples are for hyperlink control where you have to make 2 copies of the same dialog and use a mutually exclusive condition to show one or another depending on MSI version. This prevents an installer crash.  There are some scenarios where race conditions prevent property changes from reflecting in conditional expressions.  Then there's the annoyance that DoAction ControlEvents can't publish to the MSI log.  You have to do set properties to get fake logging.

Comment: It's to the point where many such as the WiX authors say forget about it and instead push external UI through their bootstrapper application (Burn).  Personally I'm aware of the internal limitations and appreciate the declarative nature and still leverage it for a basic, consistent yet attractive UI experience.

Comment: I would actually even recommend people to stay away from burn. It does some really strange things, like allowing side-by-side, same-version installations of the product and adds two or more ARP entries for the bootstrapper itself when you publish a new build and install that version; its such an abysmal annoyance, and nobody seems to care to fix it or have a good reason why it can't function the same way MSI's do; if you want a good installer, wrap your MSI in your own WPF bootstrapper; that's my advice.

Comment: I don't know if I agree.  I do agree there's a lot of complexity when you decide to use a bootstrapper and it is easier to understand your own code they yet another new framework.  But I gather Burn is pretty stable and reliable once it's understood.  Personally I have managed to avoid bootstrappers for the last several years for the most part.

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution to get this done without having to transition dialogs in order to get it to update.

In your custom action, set a property. Below, I set `INSTALLFOLDER`:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SpawnBrowseFolderDialog(Session session)
{
    session.Log("Started the SpawnBrowseFolderDialog custom action.");
    try
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(() =>
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dialog.SelectedPath = session["INSTALLFOLDER"];
            DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
            session["INSTALLFOLDER"] = dialog.SelectedPath;
        });
        worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        worker.Start();
        worker.Join();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        session.Log("Exception while trying to spawn the browse folder dialog. {0}", exception.ToString());
    }
    session.Log("Finished the SpawnBrowseFolderDialog custom action.");
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

In your `Product.wxs` file, make sure to `Publish` the property back to the UI in order to get edit boxes to update:

```
<Control Id="FolderEdit" Type="PathEdit" X="18" Y="126" Width="252" Height="18" Property="INSTALLFOLDER" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}MsiPathEdit" TabSkip="no" Sunken="yes" />
<Control Id="BrowseButton" Type="PushButton" X="276" Y="126" Width="90" Height="18" Text="{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}B&amp;rowse..." TabSkip="no">
    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="SpawnBrowseFolderDialog"><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
    <Publish Property="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]"><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
</Control>
```

So in other words, you do the action, then you must publish the property back onto itself to invoke an update in the control.

Comment: Why are using a custom action for a browse dialog instead of the built in MSI functionality?

Comment: Some of our QA staff didn't like the built-in dialogs; but it goes to show that you can do it like this if you enforce that the correct version of .NET Framework that relates to your custom action DLL target framework is on the machine first.

Comment: QA dictates installer UI?  That's messed up.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I don't leave them many bugs; I think that's likely why they tend to pick at things, but I didn't push back on this one either because I also prefer the standard .NET FolderBrowserDialog :P

Comment: But it's a custom action where one isn't needed.  Now if you told me there was a specific shortcoming of MSI UI (they exist :) ) I'd likely understand... or I'd say push configuration data to the application. :)

Comment: Functionally, the result is the same, yes, but it's just purely cosmetics, and if cosmetics get in the way, well, the only option is to change the brand of makeup. But ultimately, this one I would have had to fight for, whereas making the fix took so much less effort.