# Wix Bootstrapper Update UI (XAML) from CustomAction

Tags: wpf, xaml, wix, custom-action, bootstrapper

I have implemented a custom `bootstrapper` application (based on this tutorial http://bryanpjohnston.com/2012/09/28/custom-wix-managed-bootstrapper-application/ to install several `MSI-files`. The UI consists of several `XAML-files`. 
I use the `ExecuteMsiMessage-event` to show the user the current actions:

```
private void OnExecuteMsiMessage(object sender, ExecuteMsiMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            this.currentAction = (string)e.Data[0];
        }
    }
```

In the `bootstrapper` I use a `CustomAction` to update a `VFP-database`. Within this `CustomAction` I want to report the current steps to the user, too. Here [Wix CustomAction update UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973489/wix-customaction-update-ui) I found some information on how to update `WIX-properties`.
Is there also a way to update the property `currentAction` in my `ViewModel` from within the `CustomAction`?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your CustomAction code so it's more obvious what you're trying to achieve, but, given your current code, the following would update your viewModel:

```cs
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult MyCustomAction(Session session)
{
    Record record = new Record(0);
    record.SetString(0, "My Custom Message");
    session.Message(InstallMessage.Info, record);
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply.
Can you please tell me how to "fetch" the message in my viewModel? It is not "caught" in `OnExecuteMsiMessage`. I can see the message in the Log of the `MSI` but not in the log of the `BootStrapper`.